# Redirect customer back to product after login in Magento

Tags: magento

By default, when a customer logs in in Magento, they are redirected to their account page.

I'd like to redirect the customer back to the product/page they were visiting before.

How can I do this in Magento? I guess an observer should be the best way, but I have no idea where to start from.

Comment: Does "System" > "Configuration" > "Customer Configuration" section "Login Options" not does that when set to "no"?

Comment: Actually, it is set to «No». But I can deduce then that the login form has been rewritten somewhere. I'll find out! Thanks!

Comment: OK, I've found out why it's not working. I have this login box on the right side and the form doesn't use the referer parameter, so Magento just gives the customer to its account page. I have to find out how this referer is set there.

Answer (score 6):

```
<a href="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('customer/account/login', array('referer' => Mage::helper('core')->urlEncode($this->helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl())))?>" >Log In</a>
```

If a logged out customer is on any page on your site, once they click on this anchor tag it will lead them to login page, after they login successfully, they are redirected to the page they were on when they clicked on the anchor tag.

This is an alternative/emulator of the Login link in Magento's original "Top links" logic.

Comment: This method of setting the referrer in the URL should be the accepted answer. In my testing on v1.9.2.2, I found that setting the "before_auth_url" in the session only works when "Redirect Customer to Account Dashboard after Logging in" is set to "No" in the config, whereas the referrer-in-the-url option works even when it is set to "Yes". If it's super important that the user get back to the last page, you should use the referrer solution.

Comment: Correction on my last comment: In my testing on v1.9.2.2, I found it necessary to set the "before_auth_url" in the session AND adding the referrer in the URL as shown in this answer, in order to get the user to return back to the desired page. This is all with "Redirect Customer to Account Dashboard after Logging in" set to "Yes" in the config.

Answer (score 5):

on product page add these code

```
<?php Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setBeforeAuthUrl($this->helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl()); ?>
```

Comment: in controller this help me:
`Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setBeforeAuthUrl(Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl());`

Answer (score 1):

I have put the magento login into a lightbox popup so this code on the page before set's the referral URL.  Hope it helps.

```
<?php
   $current_url = $this->helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();
   $current_session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
   if(isset($current_session)) $current_session->setData("before_auth_url", $current_url);
?>
```

You can also put this in the head so it will set the before_auth_url on every page.  But make sure you wrap this in a conditional so it doesn't set the before_auth_url on the login pae itself.  Below is the code I used to do this.

```
<?php
if (! Mage::helper('customer')->isLoggedIn()) {
    $current_url = $this->helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();
    if((strpos($current_url, 'login') > -1) || (strpos($current_url, 'sign-in') > -1) || (strpos($current_url, 'checkout') > -1) ) {

    } else {
        $current_session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
        if(isset($current_session)) $current_session->setData("before_auth_url", $current_url);
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not so good way but it works.

```
$redirectUrl = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
echo '<script>document.location.href="'. $redirectUrl . '";</script>';
```

Answer (score -1):

The extension [Custom Login Redirect Pro](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/custom-login-redirect-pro.html) can help you. You can redirect to referer using the shortcode {{referer}}.